# Libc Version Error

Tags: 18.04, glibc

I used ubuntu 18.04 and I tried to do update libc package from 2.27 to 2.29, turn out its a bad idea and I get an error message every time I try

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The error message :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
         Recommends: libidn2-0 (>= 2.0.5~) but 2.0.4-1.1ubuntu0.2 is installed
         Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.29-0ubuntu2) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Thing I have tried :

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

And it give the same error

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

it give error message :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
         Recommends: libidn2-0 (>= 2.0.5~) but 2.0.4-1.1ubuntu0.2 is installed
         Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.29-0ubuntu2) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

another one :

```
sudo apt install -f
```

The error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
         Recommends: libidn2-0 (>= 2.0.5~) but 2.0.4-1.1ubuntu0.2 is installed
         Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.29-0ubuntu2) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: The *apt* packaging tools are designed to go to later packages automatically; but going backwards is somewhat manual and for the most part on you. From the looks of it (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libc6) you introduced 19.04 packages to your system, starting with https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libc6 which caused upgrades of other packages to meet dep rules. Restoring a backup is your fastest fix, or fully-upgrading to 19.04 & very soon to 19.10.... otherwise I think it's you fixing every package you moved off 'bionic' and into 'disco' (or re-install)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands:

```
wget http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt upgrade
```